# Webpack: Configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'extensions'

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am having strange error while using webpack-dev-server:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./index.js', './global.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'svdbundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  //mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.es6$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
  }
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'extentions'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, concord?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
   -> Options for the resolver
```